# Why doesn't yum list anything?

Tags: package-management, yum

In a Kubuntu I installed yum.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install yum                                                                                                                                                     
[sudo] password for jim:   
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
The following extra packages will be installed:  
  debugedit liblua5.2-0 librpm3 librpmbuild3 librpmio3 librpmsign1 libsqlite0 python-libxml2 python-rpm python-sqlite python-sqlitecachec python-urlgrabber rpm rpm-common rpm2cpio  
Suggested packages:  
  rpm-i18n python-sqlite-dbg alien elfutils  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  debugedit liblua5.2-0 librpm3 librpmbuild3 librpmio3 librpmsign1 libsqlite0 python-libxml2 python-rpm python-sqlite python-sqlitecachec python-urlgrabber rpm rpm-common rpm2cpio yum  
0 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 320 not upgraded.  
Need to get 1965 kB of archives.  
After this operation, 7550 kB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y  
Get:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main liblua5.2-0 amd64 5.2.2-1 [95,7 kB]  
Get:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main librpmio3 amd64 4.11.1-2 [80,8 kB]
Get:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main debugedit amd64 4.11.1-2 [16,9 kB]
Get:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main librpm3 amd64 4.11.1-2 [184 kB]
Get:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main librpmbuild3 amd64 4.11.1-2 [66,2 kB]  
Get:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main librpmsign1 amd64 4.11.1-2 [9074 B]  
Get:7 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe libsqlite0 amd64 2.8.17-8fakesync1 [188 kB]  
Get:8 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main python-libxml2 amd64 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu2 [192 kB]  
Get:9 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe python-sqlite amd64 1.0.1-9 [32,4 kB]  
Get:10 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main python-urlgrabber all 3.9.1-4ubuntu2 [48,5 kB]  
Get:11 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main rpm-common amd64 4.11.1-2 [25,1 kB]  
Get:12 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main rpm2cpio amd64 4.11.1-2 [5740 B]  
Get:13 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main rpm amd64 4.11.1-2 [135 kB]  
Get:14 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe python-rpm amd64 4.11.1-2 [43,0 kB]  
Get:15 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe python-sqlitecachec amd64 1.1.4-1 [21,4 kB]  
Get:16 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe yum all 3.4.3-2ubuntu1 [821   kB]  
Fetched 1965 kB in 1s (1537 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package liblua5.2-0:amd64.  
(Reading database ... 112109 files and directories currently installed.)  
Unpacking liblua5.2-0:amd64 (from .../liblua5.2-0_5.2.2-1_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package librpmio3.  
Unpacking librpmio3 (from .../librpmio3_4.11.1-2_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package debugedit.  
Unpacking debugedit (from .../debugedit_4.11.1-2_amd64.deb) ...  
Unpacking librpm3 (from .../librpm3_4.11.1-2_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package librpmbuild3.  
Unpacking librpmbuild3 (from .../librpmbuild3_4.11.1-2_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package librpmsign1.  
Unpacking librpmsign1 (from .../librpmsign1_4.11.1-2_amd64.deb) ...   
Selecting previously unselected package libsqlite0.   
Unpacking libsqlite0 (from .../libsqlite0_2.8.17-8fakesync1_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package python-libxml2.  
Unpacking python-libxml2 (from .../python-libxml2_2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package python-sqlite.  
Unpacking python-sqlite (from .../python-sqlite_1.0.1-9_amd64.deb) ...   
Selecting previously unselected package python-urlgrabber.  
Unpacking python-urlgrabber (from .../python-urlgrabber_3.9.1-4ubuntu2_all.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package rpm-common.  
Unpacking rpm-common (from .../rpm-common_4.11.1-2_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package rpm2cpio.  
Unpacking rpm2cpio (from .../rpm2cpio_4.11.1-2_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package rpm.  
Unpacking rpm (from .../rpm_4.11.1-2_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package python-rpm.  
Unpacking python-rpm (from .../python-rpm_4.11.1-2_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package python-sqlitecachec.  
Unpacking python-sqlitecachec (from .../python-sqlitecachec_1.1.4-1_amd64.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package yum.  
Unpacking yum (from .../yum_3.4.3-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...  
Processing triggers for man-db ...  
Setting up liblua5.2-0:amd64 (5.2.2-1) ...  
Setting up librpmio3 (4.11.1-2) ...  
Setting up debugedit (4.11.1-2) ...  
Setting up librpm3 (4.11.1-2) ...  
Setting up librpmbuild3 (4.11.1-2) ...  
Setting up librpmsign1 (4.11.1-2) ...  
Setting up libsqlite0 (2.8.17-8fakesync1) ...  
Setting up python-libxml2 (2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu2) ...  
Setting up python-sqlite (1.0.1-9) ...  
Setting up python-urlgrabber (3.9.1-4ubuntu2) ...  
Setting up rpm-common (4.11.1-2) ...  
Setting up rpm2cpio (4.11.1-2) ...  
Setting up rpm (4.11.1-2) ...  
Setting up python-rpm (4.11.1-2) ...  
Setting up python-sqlitecachec (1.1.4-1) ...  
Setting up yum (3.4.3-2ubuntu1) ...  
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
```

But when I do a list nothing is output. Does yum list what yum installed?

```
:~$   
:~$ yum list installed  
:~$
```

But when I do:

```
:~$ yum provides /etc/yum/yum.conf                                                                                                                                             
No Matches found
```

Still nothing found. Why does the yum does not list anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Because yum wasn't meant for Debian-based operating system**. If you start using two package managers the results are, most of the time, very ugly, because they are not aware of each other, they remove, replace and install files, modify configurations in a way the other package managers doesn't know and there you will have a holy mess.

If you want to install something with yum, verify 3 or 4 times that whatever yum will do is not in your system provided by APT/DPKG.

Comment: I did not know that. I read that yum is better than apt and I thought to try it.So does this mean that each manager keeps a separate database?So because yum was install with apt the file is `yum.conf` is associated only with the apt database?

Comment: Yeah. apt is the only one that knows from where the file comes from.

Comment: Yum is a really great package manager in Fedora and CentOS Linux.

Comment: @Jim, `yum` is better than `apt`, but only in the distributions it's meant for, to wit: anything derived from Red Hat.  In Debian-derived distros, `deb` packages and their managers (`apt` et al.) are better.  In Gentoo, `portage` is better.